# Can one replace the logic board of the 11-inch MacBook Air 2011 (A1370) with that of 2012 (A1465)?

Tags: repair

Can one replace the logic board of the 11-inch MacBook Air 2011 (A1370) 2Gb memory with that of 2012 (A1465) with at least 4 Gb memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. Looking at the iFixit website for these two machines will show that the logic boards are different:

[MacBook Air 11" (Late 2010) 1.4 GHz Logic Board](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Air-11-Inch-Late-2010-1-4-GHz-Logic-Board/IF108-009?o=1)
[image: Photo of front of 2010 Logic Board]
[image: Photo of back of 2010 Logic Board]

[MacBook Air 11" (Mid 2012) 1.7 GHz Logic Board](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Air-11-Inch-Mid-2012-1-7-GHz-Logic-Board/IF108-037?o=1)
[image: Photo of front of 2012 Logic Board]
[image: Photo of back of 2012 Logic Board]

Comment: I think your answer would be more convincing, if the images were of the same side of the two logic boards.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I see your point. I have added additional photos so users can see the difference.